# Qt5 application compiles on Linux and Windows, but gives cryptic error on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, qt5

I work on a small open source pc timer project. I'd love to get my client working on OS X, but I can even get it to launch! I installed xcode, and the qt5 sdk with qtcreator. When I compile I get the following warnings, but the binary compiles:

```
/Users/kylehall/Documents/Libki/main.cpp:25: In file included from ../Libki/main.cpp:25:

/Users/kylehall/Documents/Libki/timerwindow.h:20: warning: 'TIMERWINDOW_H' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]
#ifndef TIMERWINDOW_H
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

/Users/kylehall/Documents/Libki/timerwindow.h:21: 'LOGINWINDOW_H' is defined here; did you mean 'TIMERWINDOW_H'?
#define LOGINWINDOW_H
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        TIMERWINDOW_H

/Users/kylehall/Documents/Libki/timerwindow.cpp:21: In file included from ../Libki/timerwindow.cpp:21:

/Users/kylehall/Documents/Libki/timerwindow.h:20: warning: 'TIMERWINDOW_H' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]
#ifndef TIMERWINDOW_H
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

/Users/kylehall/Documents/Libki/timerwindow.h:21: 'LOGINWINDOW_H' is defined here; did you mean 'TIMERWINDOW_H'?
#define LOGINWINDOW_H
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        TIMERWINDOW_H

/Users/kylehall/Documents/build-Libki-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_clang_64bit-Debug/moc_timerwindow.cpp:9: In file included from moc_timerwindow.cpp:9:

/Users/kylehall/Documents/Libki/timerwindow.h:20: warning: 'TIMERWINDOW_H' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]
#ifndef TIMERWINDOW_H
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

/Users/kylehall/Documents/Libki/timerwindow.h:21: 'LOGINWINDOW_H' is defined here; did you mean 'TIMERWINDOW_H'?
#define LOGINWINDOW_H
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        TIMERWINDOW_H
```

When I try to run the binary I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /work/build/______________________________PADDING______________________________/lib/QtPositioning.framework/Versions/5/QtPositioning
  Referenced from: /Users/kylehall/Documents/build-Libki-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_clang_64bit-Debug/libkiclient.app/Contents/MacOS/libkiclient
  Reason: image not found
Debugging has finished
```

At this point I don't even know where to begin with such a cryptic error. Any suggestions would be great! You can grab the code and try compiling it yourself from https://bitbucket.org/libki-kms/libki-client/src

Comment: The error indicates that the build process has not fixed up the library paths in the executable. The `PADDING` is there to allow path fixup by binary patching of the executable. Try deleting the shadow build directory and build the project again. Your build environment might be messed up somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems pretty clear:

> warning: 'TIMERWINDOW_H' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]

So you must have:

```
#ifndef TIMERWINDOW_H
#define LOGINWINDOW_H
```

Copy and paste error, I'd say...

Comment: line 21 of timerwindow.h

Comment: @hexa I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: I am saying you are correct and the error is in the said line. he provided a link to his code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I fixed that issue, and not longer get any build errors. However, I still get the error when I try running the application. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Kyle use `otool -L` to see what libraries it uses. You can then set `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` or use `install_name_tool`.